# swift ios check if local notification is show

Tags: swift, swift3

I need to get local notification data from lock screen or apps was kill. Is there a way to detect it or any handler that would trigger after show?.
i try using UNUserNotificationCenter present and UNUserNotificationCenter didReceive but still not working..

Answer (score 1):

response.notification.request.content.userInfo contains the notification data

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
    guard let bodyText = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["body"] as? String else {return}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification 
                  userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
{

   if application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background 
   {
      //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
   }
}
```

Comment: Please, add explanations. Code only answers not welcomed on SO.